# How git-svn or git-flow commands are executed without dash in between

Tags: linux, git, svn, git-svn, git-flow

When installing git-flow I realized it is just putting files in /usr/local/bin mainly git-flow which is the executable, I'm able to invoke the script git-flow by running `git flow` (without dash in between). I then realized it is the same with git-svn as well where the commands are run with `git svn`.

Am I overlooking something basic or does `git` itself actually delegate the commands somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git` binary remembers the directory where dashed executables like `git-svn` are installed.  It is set during git installation, or to be more exact during build phase (that is why you need to use the same options compiling and installing).

You can find this directory with **`git --exec-path`**

```
$ git --exec-path
/usr/libexec/git-core
```

(the above is for system installation on Linux).

---

The `git svn` command (not a built in) invokes `git` wrapper, which finds `git-svn` binary, and executes it.

Note: some of dashed executables, corresponding to *built-in* commands, like `git-tag`, are hardlinked to `git` executable.  Calling those just invokes appropriate (sub)command.